# SQLite3 functions in DLL file cause unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, sqlite

I am creating a DLL in Visual Studio 2008 which requires use of SQLite3. I have included the file sqlite3.h as found [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MSERGEANT/DBD-SQLite-1.14/sqlite3.h). Right now my files only have one function, which simply takes one parameter, the database name, and opens it. My files are as follows:

**DBOPEN.H**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
__declspec(dllexport) bool OpenDatabase(std::string);
```

**DBOPEN.CPP**

```
#include "dbopen.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

bool OpenDatabase(std::string name)
{
  sqlite3 *database;
  int isOpen = sqlite3_open(name.c_str(), &database);
}
```

It's worth noting I've never written DLLs before, and I was basing the formatting on what I've found at various sources online. When I try to build this, however, I get this error:

```
1>dbopen.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced in function "bool __cdecl OpenDatabase(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?OpenDatabase@@YA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\dbopen\Debug\dbopen.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I'm honestly not really sure how to fix this. I've tried switching various things, changing function definitions, etc., but the sqlite3_open keeps causing errors. I noticed if I try to use other sqlite3 functions, they all give the same error, however the sqlite3 object definition works. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Make sure you use `__declspec(dllimport) bool OpenDatabase(std::string);` for the code that uses your dll. Normally you use a macro that will switch from dllexport to dllimport in your header depending on if you are building the dll or using the library. It does this using an additional define that you enable in your preprocessor settings when you build the dll.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, so should that be added to the declaration in the source file, since the header file already uses dllexport?

Comment: Normally you modify the header to something like `MyExport bool OpenDatabase(std::string);` Where MyExport is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll or `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll. I will see if I can find an example as this is very common.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985067/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-using-declspecdllexport Make sure you define LIBRARY_EXPORTS in the preprocessor defines of the dll only.

Comment: @drescherjm I just tried it both ways, first with the whole thing written out and then with defining MyExport, but both times I still get the "unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced" error. Wouldn't that likely indicate something wrong with that function call rather than the OpenDatabase definition?

Comment: In your dll how are you linking to a sqlite3 library or do you have sqlite3 sources as part of your dll project?

Comment: @drescherjm I don't believe it is part of the project, I have the files for it elsewhere on the computer. I did edit Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories to use the path to them.